# Create a pandas dataframe with multiple subclasses Series

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to create a pandas dataset that implements custom methods on certain columns only. I know you can override the default `pandas.Series` constructor with a subclass using something that looks like this:

**class SubclassedSeries(Series):**

```
@property
def _constructor(self):
    return SubclassedSeries

@property
def _constructor_expanddim(self):
    return SubclassedDataFrame
```

**class SubclassedDataFrame(DataFrame):**

```
@property
def _constructor(self):
    return SubclassedDataFrame

@property
def _constructor_sliced(self):
    return SubclassedSeries
```

[Pandas - Internals](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/internals.html#subclassing-pandas-data-structures) - Includes information on subclassing the pandas dataframe and series object.

What I am looking to do is to create a conditional constructor that uses the name of the column to choose the appropriate `pandas.Series` subclass. For example:

```
@property
def _constructor_sliced(self):
    if column_name == 'ANN':
        return AnnotationSeries
    else:
        return Series
```

The problem is that pandas [frame.py](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/frame.py) doesn't pass any information to the constructor - only the Series object (or subclassed series object).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting pandas to conditionally construct one of your custom Series based on its name can be done with a custom `__new__` method on the derived `pandas.Series()` like:

#### Code:

```
class SubclassedSeries(pd.Series):

    our_column_names = ('col2', )

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if kwargs.get('name', None) in cls.our_column_names:
            obj = object.__new__(cls)
            obj.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            return obj
        return pd.Series(*args, **kwargs)

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return SubclassedSeries

    @property
    def _constructor_expanddim(self):
        return SubclassedDataFrame
```

#### Test Code:

```
import pandas as pd

class SubclassedDataFrame(pd.DataFrame):

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return SubclassedDataFrame


    @property
    def _constructor_sliced(self):
        return SubclassedSeries

df = SubclassedDataFrame(dict(col1=[1, 2], col2=[3, 4]))
print(df)

print('---')
print(type(df.col1))
print(df.col1)
print('---')
print(type(df.col2))
print(df.col2)
print('---')
```

#### Results:

```
   col1  col2
0     1     3
1     2     4
---
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
0    1
1    2
Name: col1, dtype: int64
---
<class '__main__.SubclassedSeries'>
0    3
1    4
Name: col2, dtype: int64
---
```